# designing a database with facebook id and normal sign ups

Tags: mysql, database, facebook, database-design

So I am creating a website that basically allows user to sign up using their facebook account/facebook connect and just a traditional sign up (username, password). Now currently my table looks like this:

```
uid, username, password, email
```

I was thinking of how can I change this table structure to incorporate the facebook account connect as it doesn't have any username or password in it, should I just store the email and leave the username and password blank? How do other sites that have such login structure save this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll really want to store the facebook_id as well, for which I recommend using a bigint.

You might also want to add a status column that indicates whether this user account was created via email address or facebook_id, so that at login time you know which to check.  Alternately, you could just check the one that you have credentials for.

Comment: how can we detect/connect that when a user connects via his/her twitter and logs out and he logs in again using facebook that it is actually the same user?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly open ended question, and the answers depend on what your trying to accomplish, and the use cases you're trying to address. Some general thoughts/suggestions: You should also store the Facebook ID as a separate column. You can leave the username blank, as the Facebook ID can uniquely identify the user, or you can use the email as the username. If you use only Facebook connect, you don't need the password since you can use the JS SDK to make sure the user has a valid Facebook login session.